# PyDrive How to Download a Folder using ID

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am trying to download a file or folder from My Google drive using PyDrive

After multiple attempts using the Documents : https://gsuitedevs.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/filemanagement.html#download-file-conte

I still cannot seem to get my head around downloading the folder.

I have managed to list the Title and ID of my items, i just need a way to download them.

Upon listing the folders and files both with ID and title
Is there any way of downloading the folder based on the ID.

Thanks

Comment: checked this? https://gsuitedevs.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/filemanagement.html#download-file-content

Comment: yes can't seem to make sense of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have managed to get the Titles and IDs of your files. You can download them like this :

```
file = drive.CreateFile({'id': "ID_OF_YOUR_FILE"})
file.GetContentFile('FILE_NAME_AS_YOU_WANT_TO_SAVE.EXTENSION')
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!! Getting Errors though API Traceback error. (PS. I think i might be out of my daily API calls!)

Comment: Might be. You can test this piece of code tomorrow.